# Acessing the error-object from Json response

Tags: angular, object

Trying to access the object "error.errors.email" from a Json response?

[image: Console.log]

This is my form:

```
<form class="[formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    <div>
      <input formControlName="email" type="email">
      <div>{{ error.errors.email }}</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my ts:

```
submit(): void {  
    this.authService.register(this.form.getRawValue())
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('complete');
    });
  }
```

Getting error by this interpolation:

```
{{ error.errors.email }}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the returned `err` contains `me`, so probably you should do:
`this.error = err.me.error`;

also a good way to debug your template is to use the `json` pipe to see what you actually get, so for example you can do:

```html
<div>
  <input formControlName="email" type="email">
  <div *ngIf="error"> {{ error | json }} </div>
</div>
```

So you see what's inside the error variable in your template.

the other problem I see is that `email` is an array, so your interpolation should be: `{{ error.errors.email[0] }}` or add an `*ngFor`

Comment: I got this `{ "first_name": [ "The first name field is required." ], "last_name": [ "The last name field is required." ], "email": [ "The email field is required." ] }`

Comment: as you can see, first_name, last_name and email are arrays. So you should do
`.email[0]` to get the first element of the array

Comment: Got error when using this like `{{ error.email[0] }}`

Comment: you should be more specific, what kind of error did you got?  what exactly is the content of `error` ? also you may want to try to get the email in your ts file (could be simpler maybe). For example like this: `this.errorEmail = err.error.errors.email[0]`